# Unable to generate junit report in Sahi

Tags: testing, junit, junit4, automated-tests, sahi

I have a Test Suite containing 3 test cases(.xls files). Using ant script I am running the test suite but junit report generating all xmls with TEST-excelfw_firefox.xml(/temp/junit/..). So finally I got only one .xml file instead of 3. How to generate .xmls with different names using ant in Sahi?

Comment: Hi Babu, we are checking this. Will get back to you.

Comment: But in html report i am getting tc name with time stamp like "excelfw_firefox__27Aug2012__15_27_26_379.html". How can i get xml report name like this.I tried to change sahi code in JUnitFormatter.class (Changed "Test-" to currentDate at  return (new StringBuilder()).append(CurrentDate+"-").append(scriptName+CurrentDate).append(".xml").toString();) but those changes are not effected here.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed script_file.name=TEST-scriptName.xml in .\userdata\config\reports\junit\report.properties file to script_file.name=TEST-reportId.xml . Now my xml are generating with time stamp.